# Create a Multi-Column Report Using DevEx Grid

Tags: sql, grid, devexpress, reporting

I have a daily sales report query and it have 2 columns like

```
days sales
1    12
2    65
3    25
...
30   24
```

but when I want to print it there is a lots of free spaces on paper, so I want to seperate query with a percentage (like % 33)

and result will be like 3 x 2 columns for one paper. and it will be more comfortable for me.

```
days sales    days sales    days sales
1    12       11   21       21   5  
2    65       12   53       22   18
3    25       13   0       
...
10   45       20   12       30   55
```

Any way to do this with DevEx Grid?

this is the view which I get

[image: this is the view]

and I dont want such kind of empty paper for couple of records..

Comment: Updated your question to include information on your DexEv control you mentioned using.

Comment: Can you show what the output should look like, and the rules you want to implement that format?

Comment: Reporting and Grid are separate things. From your question I guess you want to print the grid but need to scale the grid horizontally on paper?

Answer (score 0):

You will not find an easy way to achieve the desired result using XtraGrid, because it is not intended for reporting. I suggest that you create reports using another product: [XtraReports](http://help.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2162).